# What is digested data?

Tags: c, openssl, digest

I'm learning OpenSSL and I found this method `BIO_f_md()` in the libtrary documentation: http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BIO_f_md.html where it says:

`Any data written or read through a digest BIO using BIO_read() and BIO_write() is digested.`

What does digest mean? What is digested data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [**cryptology lingo**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function), a digest is simply a hash value - i.e. the output of a cryptographic hash function.  Usually, the data itself is referred to as the "message", and the hash value of the data is called the "digest" or "message-digest".  So, digested means "hashed".